# JavaScript: is it possible to get the attempted name of an undefined function?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I've always wondered if there was a way of improving the error message one gets when attempting to use a function that doesn't exist (or that isn't a function). For example:

```
document.iDontExist()
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I'd like to be able to log something like:

```
document.iDontExist is not a function
```

Just to save a few seconds. I realise I have line numbers etc, I'm just wondering whether this is possible.
Is there some property of the `TypeError` I could use to look up the name that was attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - not generally.

JavaScript doesn't "send messages" to invoke functions and any expression construct can have the `()` operator applied .. none of the browser engines try to "read into" the expression to report a more useful message.

A debugger (with break-on-exception) can be useful, but otherwise no - the exceptions will remain general without manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, but if this is an option for you, it could work...

Instead of calling `document.iDontExist()`, try:

```
(document.iDontExist || logError("iDontExist undefined")) && document.iDontExist();
```

This abuses logical operators to only call the function if it exists, and log an error (assuming `logError` exists!) otherwise.